# Can I create a correlation plot using a character variable?

Tags: r, correlation, text-mining, r-corrplot

My Data set is restaurant Yelp reviews and I would like to see if there is a way to create a correlation plot between words and star ratings using the corrplot package.

I have created Z below containing the star rating, count of word (n) and word.  I am not sure where to go from here, because I know I can't directly use the word variable in a correlation plot since it is a character not a factor. If I were to just do a correlation between n and stars that doesn't actually give me any useful information. Any thoughts on how I might be able to come up with a correlation between word and stars?

```
Z <- ws %>% select(n, stars, word)
Z

# A tibble: 39,322 x 3
# Groups:   stars [5]
       n stars word     
   <int> <int> <chr>    
 1  7841     5 food     
 2  6046     4 food     
 3  4027     5 service  
 4  3741     3 food     
 5  3133     1 food     
 6  3046     4 service  
 7  2837     5 delicious
 8  2832     2 food     
 9  2803     5 love     
10  2785     5 time     
# … with 39,312 more rows
```

Comment: You could convert to `factor` with `factor` or `as.factor

Comment: I do not think that a correlation could be ok for this data, you're coercing some word to a number, maybe a tau kendall could be better but again you're assuming something strong. May I advice something like this, looking you're in tidyverse: `Z  %>% group_by(stars, word) %>% summarise(summed = sum(n))%>%
ggplot(aes (x = stars, y = word, fill = summed)) + geom_tile()` ?

Comment: @akrun I had that thought, but it's not working for me. If I enter as. factor(word) I get errorrror "in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors" I also tried  Z <- ws %>% select(n, stars, as.factor(word)) and got error "Error: unique() applies only to vectors"

Comment: `Z <- ws %>% select(n, word) %>% mutate(word = as.factor(word))` to have as factor.